# Railo: won't find default at http://domain.com

Tags: apache, coldfusion, railo

I'm having an issue with Railo 3.1.0 running under Apache on Windows Server 2003.

When going to http://www.domain.com it defaults to index.cfm.

When going to http://domain.com it doesn't find index.cfm. http://domain.com/index.cfm works fine.

Anyone know where I can configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Apache virtual host misconfiguration, not Railo. Re-check `DirectoryIndex` setting for `domain.com` site config (in sites-available), it should contain `index.cfm` on first place.

Comment: Worth mentioning this is either in `httpd.conf` (default at `C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache/conf/httpd.conf`) or in a domain-specific config (location depends on how this is setup).

Comment: @Peter You're right, thanks. I'm working only with Ubuntu-style for a while and forgot that other ways of configuring the vhosts.